# Json Rpc callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, jsonp, json-rpc

How can I pass Json Rpc data to a specified callback function, just like Json.
You can get the response data by specifying the callback parameter in the url.

For example:

```
var url = "http://...sample/..?alt=new&callback=dispUser";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

then the result would be something like this

dispUser({
        "id": ""
});

but in Json Rpc I can't, is there a way to get the response data of Json Rpc by declaring a callback. If none how would I display these data in a client side. Because I can only get these api services using Json Rpc or SOAP XML, that's what the documentation tells.

Comment: Are you thinking of _jsonp_ rather than _json-rpc_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is in JSONP style. Here's an example in JSON-RPC style:

```
var mathService;

function init() {
    mathService = RPC.consume('http://foo.bar/mathematics.smd', mathReady);
}

function mathReady() {
    mathService.cuberoot(9, function(root) {
        $('#example_output').html(root);
    });
}

window.onload = init;
```

If the JSON-RPC service doesn't describe itself via SMD, you might write something like this instead:

```
function init() {
    RPC.callMethod('http://foo.bar/mathematics.php', { 
        method: 'cuberoot', 
        params: [ 9 ]
    }, function(error, result) {
        $('#example_output').html(result);
    });
}

window.onload = init;
```

There are quite a few libraries for doing JSON-RPC from a JavaScript client (e.g: the browser), and each may be slightly different in calling convention.